# How can I make right XHR POST request in Firefox 28.0?

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, post, xmlhttprequest

My server php script POST array is empty after I make a simple XHR POST in Firefox 28.0. The request is same origin.

In my js script that triggers request I have:

```
$(function(){
$("#head").click(function(){
var invocation=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="test.php";
var body="hello";
if (invocation)
{
    invocation.open("POST",url, true);
    invocation.onreadystatechange=handler;
    invocation.send(body);
}
function handler(evtXHR){
    if(invocation.readyState===4)
    {
    if(invocation.status===200)

    {

       alert("success");
    }

    }
}
});
});
```

And in my php file I have:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$data=$_POST['body'];
var_dump($data);
?>
```

Below is the interaction between client and server:

```
Request Method:     POST
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

**Request header:**

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Referer:    .......
Pragma: no-cache
Host:   ..........
Content-Type:   text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

**Request Body:**
Hello

**Response Header**

```
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.2.17
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Server: Apache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Date:   Wed, 16 Apr 2014 19:04:55 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Connection: Keep-Alive
access-control-allow-origin:    *
```

Please,help figure out what's happening. Why POST array is empty after successful request?
Thanks.

Comment: After I made changes suggested by Quentin i still have null on var_dump $_POST in my php script, however, HTTPfox plugin shows that content is string(5) "hello" whan is use var_dump and "hello" when I use echo() in my script. How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encoding your request body as plain text. PHP doesn't parse that into `$_POST`.

Either access the raw message body…

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

or encode the data in the request in a format that PHP can understand.

```
var data="hello";
var body = "someKeyName=" + encodeURIComponent(data);

// ...
invocation.open("POST",url, true);
invocation.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
invocation.send(body);
```

and

```
$data=$_POST['someKeyName'];
```

Comment: THanks, I am not sure how to do this. I put    invocation.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/html"); in my js file, but that did not work. Should I encode plain text into different mime type?

Comment: I did everything as you suggested, but still POST array is empty.. can the problem be caused by other things?

Comment: I have NULL on var_dump($_POST["someKeyName"]), however HTTPfox plugin shows string(5) "hello", which suggests that var_dump() actually says something. Because when I put echo() instead of var_dump() in my script, HTTPfox writes just "hello" as echo() function would work

Comment: It sounds like you are still sending `data` instead of `body`.

Comment: No-no, I send body like this:
var body="name=" + encodeURIComponent(data);
and then invocation.send(body);  In php script var_dump($_POST['name']);

Comment: Thanks,but it does not work for me. May be some other mistake I'll check tomorrow(

Comment: I also see string(5)"hello" in invocation.responseText, however, nothing is printed to my test.php script. Am I right to expect that var_dump will output this text into test.php or not?

Comment: The `var_dump` function is in `test.php`. It outputs the text **from** `test.php`. Since it shows up in `responseText` you can see it is working. I don't understand what you expect to be different.

Comment: I believe it should output something in when I access mysite/test.php. Or not? when i enter mysite/test.php it outputs NULL or blank if I use echo()

Comment: If you visit `test.php` directly then you won't be making a POST request so there won't be any data to populate `$_POST` with, so `$_POST['whatever']` will be `null`, so you are still getting the expected output.

Comment: thanks, I expected $_POST to behave in a way it was not supposed to do. I thought that variable is saved in $_POST after each POST request, so I can access it after I made it. So, I mark you answer as accepted, but can you clarify where is variable saved in between requests if I cannot actually get it when accessing $_POST['whatever']. I don't quite understand that

Comment: It isn't saved anywhere between requests. If you want to save it, then you must write code to save it.

Comment: Ok, you helped me much) I can't upvote your answer since I lack credits, but I'll do is ASAP